# Unable to obtain cookies from cookiejar

Tags: go

I've constructed a simple script which goes on a website, and does a few things on there (automating a checkout process on lego.com)

This is all done using the go http client with a cookiejar on it, but when I try to print out the cookies after all the activity on the site, nothing prints - not sure if I'm doing something wrong here.

```
type Program struct {
    taskInfo task.Task
    client   http.Client
    jar      *cookiejar.Jar
    // Task Specific Variables
    maxOrderQty   string
    sessionID     string
    sku           string
    shipMethodUID string
}
```

The HTTP client is initialized below

```
func (pr *Program) initializeClient() {
    pr.jar, _ = cookiejar.New(nil)

    pr.client = http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 10,
        Jar:     pr.jar,
    }
}
```

After that, i make a few calls to the same domain (mixture of GET and POST) using said client. When I try to print out the cookies, nothing prints.

```
func (pr *Program) getSessionCookies() {
    log.Debug("Getting Cookies")
    u, _ := url.Parse("https://www.lego.com/")
    for _, cookie := range pr.jar.Cookies(u) {
        fmt.Printf("  %s: %s\n", cookie.Name, cookie.Value)
    }
}
```

Comment: To get an answer you will probably need to provide enough code to duplicate the issue (e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/SX_EK9ySNrA - this gives me two cookies). Perhaps try https://github.com/juju/persistent-cookiejar which adds, amoungst other things, an AllCookies() function (in case the cookies are not on the domain you are expecting).

Comment: The cookies might have a different path than "/" and won't show for "/". There is basically no reliable way of peeking into a net/http/cookiejar unless you exactly know what to look for. There are drop in replacements for net/http/cookiejar which let you iterate of all cookies stored but net/http/cookiejar does not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Go's http package support redirects by default, but the cookie jar must be refreshed, specially if the domain changes.

I spent a great deal of time debugging it some time ago, the solution I found was to specify a redirect handler:

```
client.CheckRedirect = getRedirectHandler(req, &client)
```

Which had the following code:

```
func getRedirectHandler(req *Request, client *http.Client) redirectHandler {
    fn := func(request *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        if req.FollowRedirect {
            log.Debug(fmt.Sprintf("Redirecting to %s", request.URL.String()))
            jar, err := getCookieJarWithURL(request.URL.String(), req.Cookies)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            client.Jar = jar
            return nil
        }
        return errors.New("Redirect not allowed")
    }
    return fn
}
```

The full code can be found in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tlopo/2561cf857237188aa563ebd4d9c6e5a4):

I hope that saves you some time :)